# Preselected ng-select value issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, select

I'm trying to get a preselected value within , i've tried multiple tutorials and looked for answers here but none worked.
Here's the deal -> 
 
I load my shifts with $http.get("api/shifts"), then:

```
 <select multiple class="form-control" ng-options="shift as shift.nom for shift in shifts" ng-model="selectedShift"></select>
```

And it goes to a modal window. But before this modal window opens, I can preselect a shift (to see who would be able to do it). In this case, I have

```
 if(preselectedShift){
  $http.get("api/shifts/"+preselectedShift._id).success(function(shift){
    $scope.selectedShift = shift; //so it's replacing the ng-model in <select>
  })
}
```

And all shifts appear as they should, but gives me no preselected shift. I also tried with a loop.

```
for (shifts.length) -> if(shift[i]._id == preselectedShift._id) ->$scope.selectedShift = shift[i]
```

Which gave me an error "value.forEach is not a function"

Nor ng-select="shift._id == preselectedShift._id" has worked (gives the same error).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're pretty close with your solution, it's just that forEach is not supported natively, if you use a for loop like so it should be good:

```
$scope.selectedShift = [];
if(preselectedShift){
    $scope.selectedShift.length = 0;
    $http.get("api/shifts/"+preselectedShift._id).success(function(shift){
        for(var x = 0; x < $scope.shifts.length; x++){
            if($scope.shifts[x]['_id'] === shift['_id']){
                $scope.selectedShift.push($scope.shifts[x]);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The reason you have to do this is because in your ng-options you use `shift as shift.nom ...` which means that in order for it to be selected it actually has to be the same reference from the array not just something equaling it. Here's a quick example explaining (hopefully) how angular checks to see if to select something:

```
var myTest = { test: 4};
var myArray = [{ test: 4 }];
var myTest2 = myArray[0];

console.log(myArray[0] === myTest); //this outputs false
console.log(myArray[0] === myTest2); //this outputs true
```

Comment: By loop i meant a for loop, not forEach. That's angular self's forEach loop. I've already tried what you're suggesting but still gives the same error:
TypeError: value.forEach is not a function
    at writeNgOptionsMultiple [as writeValue] (angular.js:26017)
    at selectDirective.link.ngModelCtrl.$render (angular.js:27893)
    at Object.ngModelWatch (angular.js:24954)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15548)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15824)
    at done (angular.js:10263)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:10435)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10376)

Comment: Can you paste what your shifts array is?

Comment: They are not exactly the same, but the only thing I need is the ID.
http://scr.hu/0ei9/1ar1w

Comment: Probably because you have multiple on it? Give my latest edit a try.

Comment: The "multiple" shouldn't be an issue. But still doesn't work :(  I'm going to see my teacher tomorrow and let you know if we find out something.

Comment: Paste more code if you can, as the tests I run with yours seem to work just fine.

Comment: OMG i  totally omitted the fact that multiple = array...you were right. With selectedShift =  [] it works ! many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with "multiple" in the select tag. Multiple means that I can select multiple options and therefore the passed object is an array.
So I had to init $scope.selectedShift = [] and  then, as Matthew suggested $scope.selectedShift.push($scope.shifts[x])

Comment: In other words the model that you're binding to has to be an array if you specify `multiple`. Thank you!